# C# End of Grid Validation

Tags: c#, datagridview

Do you know if there is any validation to know the end of a datagridview?  I'm making an update to the database but my code throws an error  at this line (if (BANDASMAGNETICAS.Exists(x => x.Equals(item.cheques_banda_magnetica)))), because there are more records in the db than the datagrid.

```
foreach (var item in objCheques)
{
   if (BANDASMAGNETICAS.Exists(x => x.Equals(item.cheques_banda_magnetica)))
   {
       string sBanda = BANDASMAGNETICAS[iBandaMagnetica].ToString();
       Ext_Cheques.ActualizarBandaMagnetica(sBanda, false);
       item.cheques_suc = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["# SUC"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_cod_aut = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["COD_AUT"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_dig_pre = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["DIG_PRE"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_cve_ope = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["CVE_OPE"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_plaza = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["PLAZA"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_banco = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["BANCO"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_dig_int = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["DIG_INT"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_cuenta = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["CUENTA"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_cheque = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["# CHEQUE"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_banda_magnetica = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["BANDA MAGNETICA"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_fecha_deposito = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["FECHA_DEPOSITO"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_fecha_liberacion = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["FECHA_LIBERACION"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_importe_cheque = dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[iBandaMagnetica].Cells["IMPORTE_CHEQUE"].Value.ToString();
       item.cheques_activo = true;
       //item.Insert();                   
   }            
}
```

Regards!!!

Comment: Could you share what's the error message you get?

Comment: Hi Phil, the error message is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
The index was out of range. It must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection value.

Comment: What's does the declaration of `BANDASMAGNETICAS` look like?

Comment: List<string> BANDASMAGNETICAS = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvBaseArchivo.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    BANDASMAGNETICAS.Add(dgvBaseArchivo.Rows[i].Cells["BANDA MAGNETICA"].Value.ToString());
                }

Comment: I'll rephrase, can you update the code in you example to include what you added in the comments?

Comment: Hi Phil, but I post the answer below. Many thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but I have to change  the whole code because the variable iBandaMagnetica throws the error when the datagrid has no more records and the objCheques collection has more.

1.- I have to assign to a datatable the datagrid(dgvBaseArchivo) source like:   `DataTable dtRegistrosTXT = (DataTable)(dgvBaseArchivo.DataSource);`

2.-Made a method named ActualizarBandaMagnetica():

```
    private void ActualizarInsertarBandaMagnetica()
    {
        if (dgvBaseArchivo.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Primero carga el archivo", "Banco Azteca Cheques");
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            Ext_ChequesCollection objCheques = Ext_Cheques.GetAll();

            foreach(DataRow row in dtRegistrosTXT.Rows)
            {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(() => this.BuscarCheque(row, objCheques));
                myThread.Start();
                Procesando++;
            }
            timerProcesar.Stop();
            FinProc = DateTime.Now;

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                cmdGuardar.Enabled = true;
                cmdUploadFile.Enabled = true;
            }));

            MessageBox.Show("Proceso Finalizado", "Banco Azteca Cheques");
        }
    }
```

With this method, I avoid the use of iBandaMagnetica over the datagrid.